# Override property in build.gradle from the command line

Tags: gradle

In `build.gradle` we can define variables like:

```
def libVersion='someVersion'
```

We can override properties in command line with `-PlibVersion=otherVersion`

Unfortunately it seems this command line option does not affect local variables defined in `build.gradle`. Is there a way to override these from command line? Please note that for some reasons i do not want to create `settings.gradle` nor `gradle.properties` files.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
ext.greeting = project.hasProperty('greeting') ? project.getProperty('greeting') : 'hello'

task greet << {
    println greeting
}
```

If you run `gradle greet`, it will print `hello`.

If you run `gradle -Pgreeting=welcome greet`, it will print `welcome`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my goal is not achievable without altering `build.gradle`, am i right?

Comment: This can be shortened to `ext.greeting = project.properties['greeting'] ?: 'hello'`

Comment: @WonderCsabo, yes, you will need to edit the `build.gradle`. If you're not looking to do any interpolation, then you could put these properties into `gradle.properties` but there are varying opinions. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html shows using the `gradle.properties` though.

Comment: this will work only if those are set in build.gradle file, not in settings.gradle

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to override a property from command line which I had defined in build.gradle but it never worked. But when I pass the property without defining in build.gradle it's working. For example:

If I use

```
def myProp='foo'
println "${myProp}"
```

and run from the cmd

```
gradlew -PmyProp=Hello build
```

Never worked. I'm always getting foo only.

But if I remove

```
def myProp='foo'
```

It's working and taking all the inputs whatever I passed from cmd.

There is another way, just define the property in gradle.properties then you can override easily from command line.

I recently experienced this with Gradle 7.3 so thought to share.