# Modify gradle BuildType based on parameter

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Here's a part of my build.gradle(Module: app)

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to call gradlew in my project directory with parameter and change "debuggable **true**" based on parameter.

So if I were to call something like:

```
gradlew build assembleDebug -Pisdebug=false
```

It should change

```
debug {
            debuggable true
        }
```

to

```
debug {
            debuggable false
        }
```

How exactly can I achieve this behaviour? I tried to create my own and was able to read parameter value, but I have no idea how to set the "debuggable" to given value.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582173/override-property-in-build-gradle-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to set a project `-P` parameter through command line.

Project parameters are accessible through project instance:

```
debug {
    if (project.hasProperty("isDebug")) {
       debuggable Boolean.valueOf(project['isDebug'])
    } else {
       debuggable true // default setting
    }
}
```

Comment: sure, I forgot, sorry!